# Function Definition in Haskell (GHCİ)

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner of Haskell. What is wrong with this expression?:

```
Prelude> let { f op [] = [] ; f op (h:t) = op h : f op t }
Prelude> f (+) []
<interactive>:337:1:
    No instance for (Show (t0 -> t0))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (t0 -> t0))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Many thanks for support.

Comment: `f` is already built-in under the name `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `(+)` has type `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a` and function `f` has type `f :: (t -> a) -> [t] -> [a]`.

`f` expects a function of one argument.

`f (+1) []` will be correct

Answer (score 2):

Your function is inferred to have this type: `(x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]`.

`(+)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`. This can be an instance of the type `(x -> y)` if we take `x` to be `a` and `y` to be `a -> a`, so all is fine. So the empty list in `f (+) []` must be of type `[a]`, and the return type must be `[a -> a]` (all of this with the same `Num a` constraint, of course). So `f (+) []` correctly computes an empty list of type `Num a => [a -> a]`.

This is all fine, but then GHCi wants to print the result of your expression. There is no way of printing values of type `Num a => [a -> a]`, because there is no way to print functions. This is basically the error GHCi is giving you: `No instance for (Show (t0 -> t0))`.

There's nothing actually wrong with your function, or with your invocation of that function. It's just that it results in an (empty) list of functions, which you can't print. If you'd `let` bound it instead, you wouldn't get an error, and you could go on to do with it anything you would normally expect to be able to do with a `Num a => [a -> a]`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the function `f` is:

```
Prelude> :t f
f :: (t -> a) -> [t] -> [a]
```

If you call the function like this:

```
Prelude> f (+) []
```

... you get the types (Let's pretend that `(+)` only works for `Int`s in this example):

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
(t -> a) = (Int -> (Int -> Int))
t = Int
a = (Int -> Int)
```

This means that the second argument to `f` is of type `[t] = [Int]` and the return type is `[a] = [Int -> Int]`. Because the return type is a list of functions, and functions cannot be shown, `ghci` will refuse to "compile" the expression because of the type errors, and you get the error that you see.

Comment: Note that the expression `f (+) []` is well typed, but not showable. For example, `null (f (+) [])` is accepted and has the value `True`.

Comment: Yes, it's the expression `print it where it = ...` that is ill-typed.

Answer (score 1):

The `f (+) []` function returns a list of functions:

```
Prelude> :t f (+) []
f (+) [] :: Num t => [t -> t]
```

And prelude trying to call `show` function on each element of the resulting list, however functions are not instances of the Show type class.